# What is the difference between watchdogd and watchdog.service?

Tags: linux

Im confused to what watchdogd is. I understand it's a kernel service/daemon for embedded Linux systems, but is it used instead of the normal watchdog daemon (watchdog.service).

Filtering `ps` shows me the process:

```bsh
# ps -ux | grep watchdog
root          74  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    23:38   0:00 [watchdogd]
```

But there is no *watchdogd* file on the system. Or does this represent the HW watchdog?